# Cognitive capacity and (memory) capacity

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I'm having difficulty finding the appropriate form of the word memory that would fit my title. It probably isn't memorial as that's a noun. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word to use here is simply **memory**:

From Wikipedia:

> In psychology, **memory** is an organism's ability to store, retain, and recall information and experiences. Traditional studies of memory began in the fields of philosophy, including techniques of artificially enhancing memory. The late nineteenth and early twentieth century put memory within the paradigms of cognitive psychology. In recent decades, it has become one of the principal pillars of a branch of science called cognitive neuroscience, an interdisciplinary link between cognitive psychology and neuroscience.

As nouns may be used as adjectives in English, *memory capacity* is unexceptionable.

Comment: I was thinking so too.